# Como Ejecutar Correctamente un evento en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

espero me puedan ayudar, este es el evento que tengo:

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `recalcula_credito_mensual`; 
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` EVENT `recalcula_credito_mensual` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2022-09-24 18:28:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE COMMENT 'recalcula los creditos cada dia cuando cumplan el mes, solo los' DO call recalcula_credito(); 
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON;
```

pero no sé por qué no se ejecuta, si yo hago una llamada al procedimiento que dice el evento, no hay problema, pero no lo quiero así ya que tiene que ser automatico.

espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: ¿Tal vez porque hasta hoy a las 18:28h no debería ejecutarse? Ponlo `EVERY 15 SEC` y podrás comprobar si funciona sin tener que esperar un día entero.

Comment: Gracias, ya modifiqué el código, pero ya me di cuenta que solo funciona local, para poder ejecutarse tengo que crear una tarea cron, si tienes un ejemplo te lo agradecería, mientras, sigo buscando